# the value of a pointer changes after the call to printf

Tags: c, memory-management

The values of pointers of a struct change after each call to printf.

I have the following structs:

```
struct block_meta_data
{
    size_t size; 
    struct block_meta_data * next; 
    int isFree; 
}; 
typedef struct block_meta_data block_meta_data;

struct list
{
    block_meta_data* base; 
    block_meta_data* end; 
}; 
typedef struct list list;
```

I defined a global variable of type list called blocks_list:

```
list blocks_list = {NULL, NULL};
```

and the main function looks like :

```
int main(void)
{
    char a[] = "hello"; 
    printf("%s\n", a); 
    return 0;  
}
```

Now, using a debugger, I observe the values of both fields of the 'blocks_list' variable before the call to printf and they both have the value NULL:
[image]

After the call to printf, the values of both fields change to:
[image]

I tried printing the values of both end and base (without using a compiler) and the issue still remains:

```
list blocks_list = {NULL, NULL}; 
int main(void)
{
    char a[] = "hello"; 
    printf("%s\n", a); 
    printf("base = %p | end = %p\n", blocks_list.base, blocks_list.end); 
    return 0;  
}
```

```
output : 
hello
base = 0x555eed65d000 | end = 0x555eed65d000
```

Can someone explain why this is happening?

Comment: That is very likely debugging artifacts. Try actually using that struct and checking if things look good while the program is actually running and the structs are still alive (i.e. before main starts to exit).

Comment: I tried printing the values of both base and end, and it still prints values different than NULL.

Comment: [mcve] then please

Comment: done! see the code bellow the question.

Comment: "done!" -- no, you have _not_ provided a _complete_ test which someone could cut/paste and compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can someone explain why this is happening?

There are a few possible explanations:

- you are not telling us the whole story (provide [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)) -- this is the most likely one
- this is a debugging artifact -- your debugger is confused and shows something that isn't *actually* happening
- the compiler detected that `blocks_list` is not actually used, and didn't allocate any storage for it (usually the compiler would also set location of `blocks_list` to `0`, which would prevent debugger from displaying it).

Since you appear to be using Linux, note that you can *tell* where the value is overwritten using GDB watch points:

```
(gdb) watch -l blocks_list.base
(gdb) continue

# GDB will stop when blocks_list.base changes its value
```

Comment: @OtmaneDaoudi Yes: defining your own `malloc`, `strcmp`, etc. will result in undefined behavior if these functions do not satisfy standard requirements, and will get invoked instead of the standard ones on UNIX (this is one major difference from Window). P.S. If the answer helped you, upvote it. If it resolved your issue, accept it -- we "work" for browny points :-)

Comment: indeed, I wasn't aware of the whole story, in short, in my code I previously defined a function called malloc,  and it seems like printf has some malloc thing going on inside of it, so instead of calling malloc from the standard library, it called my version of it, so after changing the name of my function from malloc to something else, everything works as expected.